# Logs are not being written in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I am using 3.4.0 version of Serilog.Settings.Configuration and Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights version: 4.0.0

below is my appsettings.json.

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my Program.cs.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("MyApp: Application Starting Up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "MyApp: The applicaion failed to start correctly.");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        }

        private static void ConfigureLogger()
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .Build();

            var configureLogger = new Action<IConfiguration, bool>((configuration, update) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, "Serilog")
                        .CreateLogger();

                    if (update)
                    {
                        Log.Logger.Information("MyApp: Updated logger configuration.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Logger.Error(ex, "MyApp: Failed to update logger configuration.");
                }
            });

            var updateLoggerTimer = new Timer((state) =>
            {
                configureLogger(configuration, true);
            }, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

            ChangeToken.OnChange(() => configuration.GetReloadToken(), () =>
            {
                // Use timer to debounce onchange, it fires twice when configuration changes
                updateLoggerTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            });

            configureLogger(configuration, false);
        }
    }
```

The below line is added in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

My application has the below configuration.

[image]

**No logs:**

[image]

Comment: how do you know that logs are not being written in Azure Application Insights?

Comment: Because I am not able to see any logs in `traces` or `exceptions`. I have added this info at the end of my original question now. @RomanMarusyk

Comment: Serilog.Settings.Configuration and Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights version: 4.0.0 uses connectionString, so the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING environment variable should be specified

Comment: I have added the APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING variable. it's still not logging. @RomanMarusyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous thread I came to know that you are using `ASP.NetCore 6.0`, so no need of `Startup.cs` file here.
All the code can be configured within the `Program.cs` file.

Thanks @Roman Marusyk for the comment.

Yes, you need to add the Application Insights Connection string in your `appsettings.json` file.

My `appsettings.json` file:

```cs
{ 
    "Logging": {
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug",
          "Microsoft": "Error"
        }
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    },

    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
    },

    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
          "InstrumentationKey": "****"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Application Insights using Serilog"
    }
  }
```

Thanks @[SimonCropp](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)
I have taken reference from the GitHub link.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using System;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var ConnStr = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(ConnStr, new TraceTelemetryConverter())
 .CreateLogger();


builder.Logging.AddSerilog(log);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Logger.LogInformation("Log from App");
try
{
    app.Logger.LogDebug("Debug Message");   
    app.Logger.LogWarning("Warning Message");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "MyApp: The applicaion failed to start correctly.");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

***Traces:***

[image]